# Equivalent continuation of a metric

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Hello fellow mathematicians,

I am confronted with the following, supposedly not too difficult, problem:

Let $(E,f_1)$ be a normed space and $F \subset E$ a linear subspace. Let $f_2$ be a norm on E which is equivalent with the norm $f_1$ on $F$.
Prove that there is a norm $g$ on $E$ which is equivalent to $f_1$ on $E$ and whose restriction on $F$ is $f_2$.

I tried with all the lemmata and corollaries connected with Hahn-Banach theorem, but, even though I still feel the proof should be easy, I have found no way to tackle the problem.

I would be very thankful for pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Idea: fix a number $c>0$ such that $f_2(x)\le cf_1(x)$ for each $x\in F$ and put $g(x)=\inf \{f_2(y)+cf_1(z)|y\in F, z\in E, y+z=x\}$ for each $x\in E$. At least, I used a similar construction  for topological groups (see Lemma 2 of my paper [1]).

[[1] Ravsky O.V. On Extension of (Pseudo-)Metrics from Subgroup of Topological Group onto the Group // Matematychni Studii. – 1999. – **11**, #1 – P.31-39.](http://webfile.ru/6476891)